# Android Context getSystemService: a map's awkward global state

Tags: android, design-patterns

Commonly, apps override `getSystemService` in some `Context` object and use the call to the Android system service map to obtain references to objects held by some `Context` object. This tends to mean that the `Context` object is injected everywhere and then `getSystemService` is called on it. Why not just inject the object that is needed? Or, inject one's own bundle or map?

Comment: Why the -1? Is the question too broad? I'm genuinely wondering what I'm missing, and I just wanted to hear from other devs about this pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common for custom Views.

Android's Views are typically inflated from xml layouts. This makes constructor injection problematic. These Views do get a Context object in their constructors, though. This Context object can then provide these desired dependencies with its service map.